# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported argument at parameter 0 of function

Tags: java, c++, dll, native, jna

I have an error like the title when I am using a JNA when calling for function from C.

I am developing in Java, and I want to use a function from .dll in C. I have successfully calling for another function.

This is my C header for the function..

```
    SERVICE_API BOOL apiDoTransactionEx
    ( ITransactionIn* transactionReq,
    ITransactionOut* transactionResp,
    unsigned short nApplicationNumber,
    unsigned char *inBuffer,
    unsigned long inBufferSize,
    unsigned char *outBuffer,
    unsigned long *outBufferSize );

    class ITransactionOut
    {
            public:
            virtual char* getAmount() = 0;
            virtual char* getC3Error() = 0;
            virtual char* getCurrencyCode() = 0;
            virtual char* getTerminalNumber() = 0;
            virtual char* getUserData1() = 0;
            virtual char* getPrivateData() = 0;
    };

    class ITransactionIn
    {
            public:
            virtual bool setAmount(char* amount) = 0;
            virtual char* getAmount() = 0;
            virtual bool setTermNum(char* termNum) = 0;
            virtual char* getTermNum() = 0;
            virtual bool setCurrencyCode(char* currencyCode) = 0;
            virtual char* getCurrencyCode() = 0;
            virtual bool setOperation(char* operation) = 0;
            virtual char* getOperation() = 0;
            virtual bool setAuthorizationType(char *type) = 0;
            virtual char* getAuthorizationType() = 0;
            virtual bool setCtrlCheque(char* ctrlCheque) = 0;
            virtual char* getCtrlCheque() = 0;
            virtual bool setUserData1(char* data) = 0;
            virtual char* getUserData1() = 0;
    };
```

And currently my mapping in Java is..

```
boolean apiDoTransactionEx(ITransactionIn transIn, 
                            ITransactionOut transOut,
                            int appNumber,
                            String inBuffer, //extdatain
                            long inBufferSize, //extdatainsize
                            String outBuffer, //extdataout
                            long[] outBufferSize //extdataoutsize
                            );


public interface ITransactionIn
{
        boolean setAmount(String amount);
        String getAmount();
        boolean setTermNum(String termNum);
        String getTermNum();
        boolean setCurrencyCode(String currencyCode);
        String getCurrencyCode();
        boolean setOperation(String operation);
        String getOperation();
        boolean setAuthorizationType(String type);
        String getAuthorizationType();
        boolean setCtrlCheque(String ctrlCheque);
        String getCtrlCheque();
        boolean setUserData1(String data);
        String getUserData1();
}


public interface ITransactionOut
{
        String getAmount();
        String getC3Error();
        String getCurrencyCode();
        String getTerminalNumber();
        String getUserData1();
        String getPrivateData();
}
```

But whenever I am calling the function, it will always return an error like this...

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"        
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported argument type com.cashlez.km.client.controllers.IPEKInjectorController$2 at parameter 0 of   function apiDoTransactionEx
at com.sun.jna.Function.convertArgument(Function.java:626)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:305)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:236)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.apiDoTransactionEx(Unknown Source)
```

Anybody have some alternative for the mapping?
Best Regards.

Comment: I still haven't found the right way to finishing this.. Anybody can help?

Comment: You can't just create a Java interface named after a C++ class and expect magic to happen.  How is your Java code obtaining instantiations of these interfaces?

You can pass C++ objects back and forth between native and Java as `Pointer`, but JNA doesn't know how to transform an arbitrary Java interface into a native type unless you tell it how.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I will answer my own question.

1. Use JNA,
2. Use JNAerator,
3. Copy your C++ header to JNAerator,
4. Copy paste the result to Java,and let the magic begin.

That's all I do, and it magically works.